# Open a bookmark in Safari from Terminal

Tags: terminal, safari, bookmarks

I do online tutorials one at a time and in a Safari bookmark called `Current` I always update the address to my current tutorial. I want some terminal command which I can call to start Safari and open `Current`. Starting Safari is simply an execution of `open -a safari` in the terminal.

How can I start Safari AND open the bookmark?

Answer (score -1):

```
open http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210601/open-a-bookmark-in-safari-from-terminal
```

Will open this page (in the default browser).